# trouble attaching string to url REACT NATIVE

Tags: react-native

I am having trouble attaching my string to url

```
constructor(props)
{
    super(props)
    this.state = {

        value:'',

    }
}
```

above mentioned code to get the string

```
 AsyncStorage.getItem('tokenkey', (err, value) => {
if (err) {
    console.log(err)
} else {
    //JSON.parse(value)
    this.setState({

         value: JSON.stringify(value)
    })


    console.log('sp token'+ "\t" +value)
    console.log('state token'+ "\t" +this.state.value)
}
})
```

the above code is getting token value from token key and storing to value string. Till here I did not face any problem but when I have assign this string to a url as a param to fetch it then it is printing blank space.
the url is

```
const url = "http://www.mortgagemarket.ae/web/api/get_client?token="+this.state.value
console.log('url is'+"\t"+url)
```

if I print the console url then it is printing nothing. someone please help me how to attach a string to the url

Comment: Where you are creating `url`? In `AsyncStorage.getItem` after `setState` or somewhere else?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, setState is asynchronous! I think your problem is here. Try this ->

```
  this.setState({
       value: JSON.stringify(value)
  },()=>{
    url = "http://www.mortgagemarket.ae/web/api/get_client?token="+this.state.value
  })
```

I think you are using `url` before value actually get set.
And  `AsyncStorage.getItem` is also asynchronous
so you have to use `url` inside `AsyncStorage.getItem's callback function` or you have to use `async-await`